# Why Are My Views Going Behind My Others Views While Dragging Them?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, z-index

First I'll introduce the context, as clear as possible (if needed ask it I'm able to add some screenshots).

I'm actually working on an app who's made to manage a lot of draggables views (which are called PostIts). These PostIts are stored inside others view which are non draggable.

To image it, it is like if I have 2 distant boxes with many PostIts inside:

```
| *  |                 |*  *|
|*  *|  <- distance -> | *  |
|____|                 |____|
```

**My Problem:** when I begin to drag a PostIt inside the view who's actually containing it, there is no problem. **BUT**, when I'm trying to go outside the actual view to go to the other (for exemple), the PostIt begin to disappear when it's encountering the border of the view.

```
| *  |                    |*  *|
|*  *--> disappearing..   | *  |
|____|                    |____|
```

**Go back with my imaged exemple:** that's like if when you pick a PostIt in a box and move it inside, it's all good. But when you go outside the box to go to the other, the PostIt become invisible **but you still have it in your hands** because when you drop the invisible PostIt in the other box it reappear (i've got some methods who reloads the data inside a box in sort).

```
| *  |                   |*  *|
|*  *--> disappearing --> *  *| ..reappearing
|____|                   |____|
```

**What I've tried:** Actually I'm using some things with the Z-index but that's not really concluant, I've got many bugs: (this code is actually in my `UIPanGestureRecognizer`)

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    CGPoint begin; // Creating a point because you can't directly change the x and t attribute of a point, you have to change the whole point
    begin = selectpostit.postItC.centerOfThePostit;
    begin.x -= _collectionView.contentOffset.x;
    begin.y -= _collectionView.contentOffset.y;

    selectpostit.center = begin;
}    
[self.view insertSubview:selectpostit aboveSubview:self.view];
```

Here are 10 others try which wasn't concluant:

```
   CGPoint tmpPoint = selectpostit.center;
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:selectpostit];
    selectpostit.center = tmpPoint;
    self.view.layer.zPosition=1;
    self.collectionView.layer.zPosition=1;
    selectpostit.layer.zPosition = 1;
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:selectpostit];
   [_collectionView bringSubviewToFront:selectpostit];
   [selectpostit.superview bringSubviewToFront:selectpostit];
   [self.view insertSubview:selectpostit atIndex:1];
```

Perhaps I'm not well using these methods?

**My question:** isn't there a simple way to put a view in front of **all the other view** (absolutely every all other) when we're beginning a dragNdrop (so with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`) ?

PS: It should be a lot of grammar mistakes in there, sorry, I'm a french-native and that's a bit complicated to well explain me without mistakes, feel free to correct them if you see them.

Comment: Be sure that the `clipsToBounds` property of the PostIt container view has `NO` value.

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow when I'll be at work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you were right, put this as answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the `clipsToBounds` property of the PostIt container view has NO value.